# Boot Partition Full

Tags: boot, partitioning, software-recommendation, update-manager

When I run Software Updater, it says that I don't have enough free disk space. I need 29.3 Mb of free disk space on '/boot'. I've tried the solution at [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot). It removed a lot, but I need more. I am running the newest version of Ubuntu Studio. Here's some data:

```
joseph@joseph-UX31A:~$ df
Filesystem                          1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--studio--vg-root 114276968 7642152 100806824   8% /
none                                        4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                                  1949692       4   1949688   1% /dev
tmpfs                                  393156    1400    391756   1% /run
none                                     5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                                  1965764      80   1965684   1% /run/shm
none                                   102400      40    102360   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2                              241965   95551    133922  42% /boot
/dev/sda1                              523248    3428    519820   1% /boot/efi


joseph@joseph-UX31A:~$ ls -as /boot
total 85833
1 .
4 ..
1143 abi-3.13.0-35-generic
1144 abi-3.13.0-35-lowlatency
163 config-3.13.0-35-generic
163 config-3.13.0-35-lowlatency
4 efi
1 grub
29502 initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
29446 initrd.img-3.13.0-35-lowlatency
12 lost+found
174 memtest86+.bin
175 memtest86+.elf
176 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
3322 System.map-3.13.0-35-generic
3319 System.map-3.13.0-35-lowlatency
5695 vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
5697 vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic.efi.signed
5692 vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-lowlatency

joseph@joseph-UX31A:~$ uname -a
Linux joseph-UX31A 3.13.0-35-lowlatency #62-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 15 02:26:48  UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks Guys, I've been at this for a while, kinda stressed.

Comment: Do you need the lowlatency kernel for something in particular?+

Comment: Yes, music production.

Comment: What am I missing?  It looks like you have about 134MB free on /boot, and more on /boot/efi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after cleaning, we can see you have two different kernels left: **generic** and **lowlatency**.

The **uname** command shows that you are using the **lowlatency**. If you are not using the **generic** kernel, you could delete its related files by running :

```
sudo find /boot -name "*generic*" -delete
```

This should halves the space used in **/boot**.

You could/should also grow your **/boot** partition by using **gparted** in a live-CD session for example, but you will probably have to shrink adjacent partition.